# Using Django ORM, how do I filter against two fields of the same record in a Many relationship?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a DB schema like so:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family)

    name   = models.TextField()
    age    = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

I want a query that returns all children in families that have boys under 5.

How do I express this? Closest I got is:

```
# WRONG: this is no good, it will only return boys under 5, but I want all
# children in families with boys under 5.
Child.objects.filter(gender='M', age__lt=5)

# WRONG: this is no good, it is closer but will also return children in 
# families with a 6yo boy and a 3yo girl.
Child.objects.filter(family__child__gender='M', family__child__age__lt=5)
```

Comment: db.Model? where is that coming from?
You have pass in your Family with no specs, you are trying to filter on a remote field (family__child)...
`filter(gender='M', age__lt=5)`

Comment: models.Model not db.Models

Comment: I edited my question to fix it to `models.Model`, thanks.

Comment: @petkostas: I think I addressed your second point in a new example I just added.

Comment: You can try an ``__in``-query like this: ``boys_under_5 = Child.objects.filter(gender='M', age__lg=5); Child.objects.filter(family__child__in=boys_unter_5)``

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) your second query should work as intended, going back as far as Django 1.2, and my testing confirms that. Is this the exact query you're using?

Comment: @sk1p: Your comment is a correct answer - make it an actual "Answer" so we can upvote/mark as correct.

Comment: @knbk: Your comment is a correct answer also - make it an actual "Answer" so we can upvote/mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @knbk pointed out in a comment, I was actually wrong when I wrote the question.  I assumed a default behavior that wasn't there.  The best answer, then, is the one I gave:

```
Child.objects.filter(family__child__gender='M', family__child__age__lt=5)
```

If you wanted to retrieve all children in families with a male child and one (possibly a different one) who is under 5, you'd have to do this:

```
Child.objects.filter(family__child__gender='M').filter(family__child__age__lt=5)
```

And here's the documentation link @knbk provided which details the feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

If he answers, I'll move the points to him.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you wanted all boys in families with boys under 5
It's a big ambiguous but I'm going to assume that you want families that contain at least one boy that is under 5

This would work:

```
families = Family.objects.filter(child__gender='M', child__age__lt=5).prefetch_related('child')
```

Then you could iterate over the family objects to retrieve their respective children

Answer (score 1):

Get the `id`s of the `Family`s that have boys under 5, then filter `Child` on those `id`s. The following query only hits the database once:

```
Child.objects.filter(
    family__in=Family.objects.filter(child__gender='M', child_age__lt=5).values('id')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an `__in`-query like this:

```
boys_under_5 = Child.objects.filter(gender='M', age__lg=5)
Child.objects.filter(family__child__in=boys_unter_5)
```

As to why your original query doesn't work, I suggest reading the generared SQL:

```
print Child.objects.filter(family__child__gender='M', family__child__age__lt=5).query
```